# Perl - Capturing an unexpected termination

Tags: multithreading, perl

I have some code that spawns 5 threads of itself, at a time.  I detach those threads, but have a shared variable `$THREADCOUNT` that I increment at the beginning of the subprocedure that is called by the thread call, and decrement at the end of the thread.  When `$THREADCOUNT` equals 0, I spawn another 5 times.

The problem is, sometimes the thread exits unexpectedly and the `$THREADCOUNT` never makes it to 0, so the program stops.  Is there someway to capture an exit like this and have `$THREADCOUNT--` on unexpected exit?

Thanks so much.  This is my first post so appologies if it's a little unclear.

Chris

Answer (score 1):

Is the shared `$THREADCOUNT` variable really necessary? A call to `threads->list(threads::running)` will tell you whether any of your spawn are still running.

Answer (score 1):

I can't figure out when anyone would ever want to use `detach`. I'd use something like

```
use threads;

my %workers;

sub start_worker {
   my $thread = threads->create(@_);
   $workers{$thread->tid} = $thread;
   return $thread;
}

sub collect_finished_workers {
   for my $thread (threads->list(threads::joinable)) {
      $thread->join()
         if delete($workers{$threads->tid});  # Don't assume we own all threads.
   }
}

sub get_worker_count {
   collect_finished_workers();
   return 0+keys(%workers);
}
```

Note that this fixes the problem in your code where a thread isn't counted as started for a short while after it has started.